# How to hide Bootstrap previous modal when you opening new one?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have such trouble: I have authentification which is made using Bootstrap modals.

When user opens sign in modal he can go to sign up modal ( or other ) . So, I need to close previous one.

Now I'm closing them like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").click(function() {
  $("#login").hide();
  $("#sign_up").hide();
 })  
});
```

but when I'm doing this - I can't reopen sign in modal( after click on sign up from sign in) until I refresh the page.

**Can someone suggest how to check on what modal I'm clicking on the link and close it, when call another one ? Is there any universal way to close previous modal ?**

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You hide Bootstrap modals with:

```
$('#modal').modal('hide');
```

Saying `$().hide()` makes the matched element invisible, but as far as the modal-related code is concerned, it's still there. See the Methods section in the [Modals documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals).

Comment: willglynn, I know how to hide it, but I need help in some logic. Can I create example and you will look at it ?

Comment: Your example shows hiding with `$().hide`, rather than with `$().modal('hide')`. But yes, a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be helpful.

Comment: Yeah, it is working better, than mine) I am not concentrated. Thanks YOU)

Comment: Tis worked, Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Toggle both modals

```
$('#modalOne').modal('toggle');
$('#modalTwo').modal('toggle');
```

Answer (score 1):

The best that I've been able to do is

```
$(this).closest('.modal').modal('toggle');
```

This gets the modal holding the DOM object you triggered the event on (guessing you're clicking a button).  Gets the closest parent '.modal' and toggles it.  Obviously only works because it's inside the modal you clicked.

You can however do this:

```
$(".modal:visible").modal('toggle');
```

This gets the modal that is displaying (since you can only have one open at a time), and triggers the 'toggle'  This would not work without ":visible"